# Access HtmlHelper right after it is created, and before the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper, application-start

I know that i from Application_Start can ActionFilterAttribute add a custom global filter and manipulate the ModelState and what not.

Is there a similar way, to access the @Html (HtmlHelper) Before it get's send to the view?

The reason for this is that i want to edit (or remove and recreate) the UnobtrosiveValidationAttributes. And if i try to do that in the View like this: `@Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("PhoneNumber").Clear();` Nothing happens, but i'm thinking it might would work if i got to it earlier?

(If you are wondering why: i need to translate the ErrorMessages inside)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there are ways to intercept where the unobtrusive validating code is assigning the message text.  I'm not sure that it's the best idea either because one property could have many different validations (Required, Regex, StringLength, etc...)

I can tell you there are other ways to localize error messages though.  One way that works out of the box is to use resource files and to define a resource key instead of an error message.

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="resource-key")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Another way that works but requires writing more code is to create your own custom validators that retrieve your error messages from wherever they are stored.  I had to recently do this because all of our localization happens in the database.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My localization is also in the database, and i'm really trying hard not use the approach you mention. I would rather not use unobtrusive javascript at all, than doing it that way. I could make my own CustomRequiredAttribute, and i would where it not for EF CodeFirst where i need the required attribute for my designing my database..

Comment: Can you separate your view models from your entity framework entities?  If you can, then put your CustomRequiredAttribute on your view models, and continue to use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required on you entity framework entities.

Comment: Also, you should be able to use your CustomRequiredAttribute on your entity framework entities since it will also inherit from ValidationAttribute.

Comment: Yah your right Rick, thought about it. But i really when the entitie and the ViewModel are one and the same. Yeah maybe i can make my custom attributes do the same as the original once. Will look in to it.